# How can I get pyautogui to print words from a string?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm working on a project which I want to be able to take words separated by a space, turn it into a string using .split() and then have pyautogui print it out with an "enter" being pressed in between each word. This is the code I have so far below.

```
# Importing stuff
import pyautogui

# Configure Typing Thing
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0

# Input
input = "hi this is a test run of this program"

# generate words
output_list = input.split()

pyautogui.write(output_list)
pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Could someone tell me what I did wrong while writing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0

input = "hi this is a test run of this program"

output_list = input.split()

for x in output_list:
    pyautogui.write(x)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not use the word input as a variable name as it is a builtin function in Python. To print the words with an enter between them use the following code:

```
ipt = "hi this is a test run of this program"
ipt = ipt.split()
for word in ipt:
    pyautogui.write(word + "\n")
```

The "\n" is interpreted as a new line character and therefore the write function prints it as a new line (aka an enter)

EDIT: Even easier is something where you replace every space in the string with a newline character and then write that. For example:

```
ipt = "hi this is a test run of this program"
ipt = ipt.replace(" ", "\n")
pyautogui.write(ipt)
```